# How to make a grep which excludes a bunch of pipes?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to make a diff of hostnames using grep. I have 2 files. One yaml and one .pp. In the yaml I have domain names with ips and in the .pp file I have fqdn and ip in hash style. Like this:

In the fist file I Have a list of hosts:

> {host => host1, ip = x.x.x.x },
>
> {host => host2, ip = x.x.x.x },

In the second file I have another group of hosts like this:

> host1:
>
> ip: x.x.x.x
>
> host2:
>
> ip: x.x.x.x

I'm trying first to get the list of hosts of the first file and at the same time get the list of hosts of the second file. 
If the host of the first file is in the second one I skip it.

`cat FILEONE.pp | grep 'host =>' | 
grep -v "cat FILETWO.yaml | grep '[0-9]:' | grep -v ip"`

Filter

I want to pass this: `"cat FILETWO.yaml | grep '[0-9]:' | grep -v ip"` as parameter to the `-v` flag to the previous grep to make an inverse grep but I can't make it work...

Is it possible to make this on the fly?

The question could be reduced to:

How can I make this:

`grep -v {cat file | command2 | command3 | command4}`

I want to make a list which contains the hosts in the first file only if they are not in the second file. (Exclude the hosts of the second file from the first file)

Comment: Why dont you just use diff -u?

Comment: Because with diff the lines would not match. I am getting a substring of the lines to filter in the other file. But this question would apply for a lot of things :)

Comment: I've read your question a couple of times and topped up with coffee and I still don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain with a simple example please?

Comment: @lain I posted an example... hope it's clear

Comment: It is not very clear, but you could give some feedback to the answers to complete it.

Comment: Made some edits. If it's not very clear yet please tell me.

Comment: @AAlvz it is not us chasing you, but you providing input to the people who answered.

Comment: @fedorqui sure! I just want everything to be as clear as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cat FILEONE.pp | grep "host = $(cat FILETWO.yaml | grep '[0-9]:' | grep -v ip)"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... It the same output as the command I posted...

Comment: Oops, made a little edit to my command (the first `grep` also had `-v` which not what you wanted). Try it now.

Comment: Nope... I got nothing.. And I'm using the `-v` to exclude all those coincidences

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work the way you need:

```
for host in $(awk '{print $3}' FILEONE.pp | sed "s/,//"); do grep -q $host FILETWO.yaml || echo $host; done
```

This print a list of the hosts in the first file only if they are not in the second file.

Comment: This is almost what I want. The only thing is that on the yaml file I just have jhostnames and in the .pp file fqdn. I fixed the first first `awk` to improve that but i still don't get exactly what I want... Why using `grep -q` ?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is best for these things:

```
awk -F"[: ,]*" 'FNR==NR && /:$/ {a[$1]; next} $3 in a' f2 f1
```

Just loop through the second file storing the names of hosts in the array `a[]`. Then, loop through the first file checking if the 3rd field is in the array.

Note `-F"[: ,]*"` is used to set the field separator as either `:`, `,` or spaces.

#### Test

Given these sample files:

```
$ cat f1
host = host1, ip = x.x.x.x
host = host2, ip = y.y.y.y
host = host3, ip = z.z.z.z
$ cat f2
host1:
ip: x.x.x.x
host3:
ip: x.x.x.x
```

See output:

```
$ awk -F"[: ,]*" 'FNR==NR && /:$/ {a[$1]; next} $3 in a' f2 f1
host = host1, ip = x.x.x.x
host = host3, ip = z.z.z.z
```

Comment: I still don't get this command entirely. Could you give more explanetion please? I'm trying to make it work for my needs because right now I just get the list of hosts of `f2`